# Expandable listview with group and child checkbox giving null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

```
I have an expandable listview with checkboxes in group and child.
```

What I want is when I check on group checkbox , all its child items should get checked. 
But I'm getting null pointer exeption when I'm running program. Here is my code......thanks

```
//ExpandableListAdapter.java:

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    /*list of group */
    private ArrayList<Group> groups;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> isCheckedHeader=new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Boolean>> IsCheckedChild;


public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Group> groups,ArrayList<Boolean> isCheckedHeader,HashMap<String, ArrayList<Boolean>> IsCheckedChild) {
    super();
        this.groups=groups;
        this.isCheckedHeader=isCheckedHeader;
        this.IsCheckedChild=IsCheckedChild;
        inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    /**
     * @param child
     * @param group
     *  use for adding item to list view
     */
    public void addItem(Child child,Group group) {
        if(!groups.contains(group)) {
            groups.add(group);
        }
        int index=groups.indexOf(group);
        ArrayList<Child> ch=groups.get(index).getChildrens();
        ch.add(child);
        groups.get(index).setChildrens(ch);
    }

    public Child getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        ArrayList<Child> ch=groups.get(groupPosition).getChildrens();

        return ch.get(childPosition);
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        ArrayList<Child> ch=groups.get(groupPosition).getChildrens();
        return ch.size();
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Child child= (Child) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
        TextView childName=null;
        if(convertView==null) {
          convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);
        }

        final CheckBox chkChild=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxC);
        childName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChildName);
        childName.setText(child.getChildName());
        chkChild.setChecked(IsCheckedChild.get(this.groups.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition));

        final int iGroupPos = groupPosition;
        final int iChildPos = childPosition;

        chkChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(chkChild.isChecked()) //the child was enable (checked)
                {
                    IsCheckedChild.get(groups.get(iGroupPos)).set(iChildPos, true);
                }
                else //the child was disable (non-checked)
                {
                    IsCheckedChild.get(groups.get(iGroupPos)).set(iChildPos, false);
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
    public Group getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView groupName = null;
        Group group=(Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if(convertView==null) {
          convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view, null);         
        }   

        groupName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewGroupName);
        groupName.setText(group.getGroupName());
        final CheckBox chkParent=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxH);
        chkParent.setChecked(isCheckedHeader.get(groupPosition));
        final int iPos = groupPosition;
        chkParent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(chkParent.isChecked()) {
                    isCheckedHeader.set(iPos, true);
                    //Checking all SubItem(Childs) of this
                    int iSizeChilds = getChildrenCount(iPos);
                    for(int i=0;i<iSizeChilds;i++) {
                        IsCheckedChild.get(groups.get(iPos)).set(i, true);
                    }
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

//Group.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Group {
    public String groupId;
    public String groupName;
    public ArrayList<Child> childrens;
    public Group(String groupId, String groupName,
            ArrayList<Child> childrens) {
        super();
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.groupName = groupName;
        this.childrens = childrens;
    }
    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }
    public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }
    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }
    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }
    public ArrayList<Child> getChildrens() {
        return childrens;
    }
    public void setChildrens(ArrayList<Child> childrens) {
        this.childrens = childrens;
    }

}

//Child.java:

public class Child {
    public String chiledId;
    public String childName;
    public Child(String chiledId, String childName) {
        super();
        this.chiledId = chiledId;
        this.childName = childName;
    }
    public String getChiledId() {
        return chiledId;
    }
    public void setChiledId(String chiledId) {
        this.chiledId = chiledId;
    }
    public String getChildName() {
        return childName;
    }
    public void setChildName(String childName) {
        this.childName = childName;
    }
}
```

//In MainActivity items are added dynamically.

```
    MainActivity.java:

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /*our expandable adapter */
    ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
    /*expandable list*/
    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    /*list items*/
    ArrayList<Group> groups=new ArrayList<Group>();
    ArrayList<Boolean> isCheckedHeader;
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Boolean>> IsCheckedChild;
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        isCheckedHeader=new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        IsCheckedChild=new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Boolean>>();
        /*genarate data for list view*/
        genarateData();
        /*instantiate adapter with our item list*/
        expandableListAdapter=new ExpandableListAdapter(this, groups,isCheckedHeader,IsCheckedChild);
        /*we get list view*/
        expandableListView=(ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        /*set adapter to list view*/
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    //Generate dummy data for list view
    public void genarateData() {
        Group group;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            ArrayList<Child> childrens=new ArrayList<Child>();
            childrens.clear();
            Child child;

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                child=new Child(""+j, "Child "+j);
                childrens.add(child);   
            }
            group=new Group(""+i, " Group "+i, childrens);
            groups.add(group);
            isCheckedHeader.add(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my logcat.

```
09-16 03:24:19.341: I/Process(1863): Sending signal. PID: 1863 SIG: 9
09-16 03:24:27.871: D/dalvikvm(1903): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 59K, 5% free 2949K/3092K, paused 31ms, total 32ms
09-16 03:24:27.871: I/dalvikvm-heap(1903): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.562MB for 635812-byte allocation
09-16 03:24:27.921: D/dalvikvm(1903): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 3567K/3716K, paused 40ms, total 40ms
09-16 03:24:28.441: D/AndroidRuntime(1903): Shutting down VM
09-16 03:24:28.441: W/dalvikvm(1903): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a12ba8)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903): Process: com.android.guide.expandablelistview, PID: 1903
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at com.android.guide.expandablelistview.ExpandableListAdapter.getGroupView(ExpandableListAdapter.java:117)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:446)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-16 03:24:28.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-16 03:25:11.961: I/Process(1903): Sending signal. PID: 1903 SIG: 9


How can I correct this?
PS:I'm a beginner. Thanks :)
```

Comment: post your log trash.and which place you will get the exception.?

Comment: I get the error straightaway when I run the program.

Comment: post the log, it has more info than you think. I can guess   **isCheckedHeader** and **IsCheckedChild** is not initiated if this is your complete code

Comment: @BLackBeard I've added the logcat.

Comment: show the line at ExpandableListAdapter.java:117

Comment: Check if **groupName** or **chkParent** is null. See if the id's are present
Advice use **SparseArray<SparseBooleanArray>** instead of **HashMap** and **ArrayList**

Comment: @prakash Here is the line.      chkParent.setChecked(isCheckedHeader.get(groupPosition));

Comment: Did you Check if groupName or chkParent or isCheckedHeader is null?

Comment: How to check it? @BlackBeard

Comment: `But I'm getting null pointer exeption when I'm running program.` Just when you start your app? If not, which action is invoked by the user?

Comment: As said earlier by @BlackBird: You are doing nothing in the adapter with `private ArrayList<Boolean> isCheckedHeader;`. It is not initialized. You should do that in the constructor first. Like you initialise `ArrayList<Group> groups`.

Comment: @greenapps I've initialised it. And I added isCheckedHeader.add(false); in generateData() but still not working , it gives IndexOutofBoundsException. :(

Comment: Please add it in your code so we can see. How many times did you add a `false`? How many would you need do you think? For the whole list! For all the items in your adapter!

Comment: @greenapps I've updated the code here. I was editing this program http://www.mobiledevguide.com/2012/09/how-to-work-with-android.html

Comment: `it gives IndexOutofBoundsException` on which array? Reread teh first comment of @BlackBeard. Should we tell you things ten times if you have ten lists? Or would one time suffice? Do we have to tell the same for both of your lists?

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

use the `final Parent parent = parents.get(groupPosition);` instead of using the

```
Group group=(Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
```

and then change checkbox setcheck-

```
CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
checkbox.setChecked(parent.isChecked());
```

look at this link:[link](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129)

Comment: Not working.Group is the name of parent bean class. How can I give Parent instead of Group?

Comment: I have found the arraylist isCheckHeader is null. Thats why it is showing null ponter exception. But I dont know where to add to that arraylist.

Comment: add your boolean arraylist in genarateData(); in mainactivity

Comment: I have given isCheckedHeader.add(false); inside generateData(); but  it now showing IndexOutofBoundsException. :( Ive given it below Group group statement.

Comment: I was editing this program http://www.mobiledevguide.com/2012/09/how-to-work-with-android.html

Comment: how you get the group name,same way you add the boolean data in group at generateData() in mainactivty.  add like this,group=new Group(""+i, " Group "+i, childrens , false); and change the function in group class

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not properly initialized all the objects. some object are having value. Please check you 
initialized the objects properly.